# Boost Asio serial_port - need help with io

Tags: c++, boost

So I've been trying to learn the boost::asio stuff to communicate to a serial device using RS232.  The documementation is sparse and the examples are non-existent.  Can't figure out exactly how to communicate with the device.  The device can't send data so all I need to do is write, but other projects require actual back and forth communication so help with that would be appreciated.  What code I have so far follows.

```
#include <boost/asio/serial_port.hpp>
using namespace::boost::asio;

int main()
{
    io_service io;
    serial_port port( io, "COM3" );
    port.set_option( serial_port_base::baud_rate( 19200 ) );

    unsigned char commands[4] = { 1, 128, 240, 0 };

    // write the commands to the device

    return 0;
}
```

In short: need help with the io part of the serial_port.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In addition to the baud rate, you may also need to set other options like: character_size, flow_control, parity and stop_bits. To write your data to the serial port you can do the following:

```
boost::asio::write(port, boost::asio::buffer(commands, 4));
```

The libraries acceptance of buffer types is very flexible and you may want to read further on that topic here: [Buffers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/buffers.html).

Comment: Thanks, was mostly overwhelmed with the number of options and needed somewhere to get started.  I lucked out because the defaults values for everything except baud rate are what the board uses.

Answer (score 16):

Thanks to the help from here and other places I got it working.  Wrote a small program that might help some people figure out the boost serial port stuff as well.

[boostserialportdemo.cpp](http://www.college-code.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/boost_serial_port_demo.cpp)

Comment: the linux version of your demo should use /dev/ttyS2.  Linux devices use 0 based numbering

Comment: I'm getting 404 on that page. Would you mind uploading it somewhere else? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wondering why his example gives a compile error, change CSIZE to C_SIZE on both lines. This is probably the only good example program on the web.
[Thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641149/serial-port-configuration-using-boost-asio).